# How to include two table in route node?

Tags: node.js

I am creating a route I would like to put two add in to add two tables and store the data in my intermediate tables. My first table only passes the second no. I think I have a syntax error that I can't find by desperately searching. Here is my code

```
router.post("/new_recette", (req, res) => {
    var idmateriel = req.body.materiel;
    var idingredient = req.body.ingredient;
    db.recette.findOne({
            where: { nom: req.body.nom }
        })
        .then(recette => {
            if (!recette) {
                db.recette
                    .create({
                        nom: req.body.nom,
                        temps: req.body.temps,
                        cout_pers: req.body.cout_pers,
                        pdf: req.body.pdf,
                        image: req.body.image,
                        cat_recetteId: req.body.cat_recette
                    })
                    .then((recette) => {
                        console.log(recette);
                        recette
                            .addMateriels(idmateriel)
                            .then((recettes) => {
                                res.json(recettes);
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                res.json(err);
                            })

                    })
                    .then((recette) => {
                        console.log(recette);
                        recette
                            .addIngredients(idingredient)
                            .then((recettes) => {
                                res.json(recettes);
                            })
                            .catch((err) => {
                                res.json(err);
                            })

                    })

                .catch((err) => {
                    res.json(err);
                })
            } else {
                res.json(" déja dans la base ");
            }
        })
```

Comment: Sorry, but Stackoverflow is an English only site. Please translate your question.

Comment: What is the error that you get when you run it?

Comment: Hi @Sophie and welcome to our community! In order to help you, one needs more information, about: what are you trying to achieve, what have you done so far in order to solve problem, and what are the errors you get. It is always helpful to provide more information then less :D. Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Can you comment out '// res.json(recettes);' and '// res.json(err);' and just console result in first '.then', and see what happens. Seems like part of the code dealing with second table is never accessed. Let us know what solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few errors in your code so I just add a solution that I'd personally would use and provide you some extra info.

So this is what I've come up with, from the top of my head, so it cancontain some errors. If you work with promises IN promises, you need to return that promise chain as well, otherwise it won't work.
So in my example I use `Promise.all` and I explicitly return that promise so it can be chained further down the line. If you miss a return statement, your code won't wait properly and it can either behave very funky or not at all.
Also, write to the response buffer once. I think `resp.json` flushes and closes the response stream so you cannot call it twice. If you want that, use `resp.append` instead.
That's why I only return the raw data from the first few promises and only in the last step I send it back to the client.

My code returns an array of 2 objects; the output of both `recette.addMateriels` and `recette.addIngredients`. As in your code you write both responses to the response stream, I figured this is what you'd want. If not, you can easily adjust it from there.

```
router.post("/new_recette", (req, res) => {
    const idmateriel = req.body.materiel;
    const idingredient = req.body.ingredient;

    return db.recette.findOne({where: {nom: req.body.nom}})
      .then((dbRecette) => {
        if (dbRecette) {
            return ' déja dans la base ';
        } else {
            return db.recette.create({nom: req.body.nom})
                .then((recette) => {
                    return Promise.all([
                        recette.addMateriels(idmateriel),
                        recette.addIngredients(idingredient)
                    ]);
                });
        }
    })
    .then((result) => {
        res.json(result);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        res.json(err);
    });
});
```

Give this a shot and see where it takes you.